# Is there an alternative to `read` that returns Maybe?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a number from IO like this:

```
numberString <- getLine
print 3 + read numberString
```

This works if `numberString` is a good string of number (like "3241"), but when it's not something that good (like "124gjh"), it throws an exception:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

There's a `reads` function which returns a `[(a0, String)]` and when nothing is matched this would be a `[]`. Is there an easy way that I have something like this:

```
read' :: String -> Maybe a
```

so that I just get a `Nothing` if things doesn't work instead of just stopping abruptly?

Comment: [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) ;) ... you can always [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+Maybe+a) for those (although [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Read+a+%3D%3E+String+-%3E+Maybe+a) does better here)

Comment: @Carsten Why doesn't `readMaybe` show up in the Hoogle results for that query though?

Comment: @ChrisMartin I have honestly no clue - seems Hoogle does not *see* `Text.Read` even though it's in base

Comment: An alternative answer, if you don't want to use `Text`, is given by [the first Hoogle result](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgi-3001.3.0.0/docs/src/Network-CGI-Protocol.html#maybeRead): `maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads`

Comment: There's things like `Hoogle`?! Oh.... thanks guys

Comment: yeah - but it's better to look for it on Bing ;) ... Google will just think that you misspelled it's name ^^

Comment: @ChrisMartin They may have cached the `base` package a long time ago, any function marked as `Since 4.6.*.*` won't show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) right in `Text.Read` which should do exactly what you asked for:

```
Prelude> import Text.Read(readMaybe)
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "3241" :: Maybe Int
Just 3241
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "Hello" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

Comment: and `readEither` which will give you the reason why it failed (parse error)

Comment: well `Left "Prelude.read: no parse"` might not be as surprising here ^^ (and yes it might be ambiguous too but I never saw this *in the wild*)

Comment: oh, I guess I never really checked what Left was :) good to know, thanks!

Comment: @Carsten It can also be `Left "Prelude.read: ambiguous parse"`.

Comment: @PyRulez yes that was my comment in (...) - but as I said: I never saw this actually happen - and I think there was an question here or on reddit where nobody could produce one with the usual `Read` instances as well (last time I checked - but probably some smart guy found some way)